# Set JTable selectable but not editable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

i'd like to set my JTable selectable but not editable.
What is the best way to do this in my code?

```
    DefaultTableModel table = toernooi.getToernooien();

    tbl_toernooi.setModel(table);
    tbl_toernooi.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure that the [`isCellEditable()` method of the table model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29) of the table returns false. The DefaultTableModel implementation of this method returns true, so you'll have to subclass it, and override the method to return false.